# Homegroup libraries visible but can't be opened

Tags: windows-7, home-networking, file-sharing, libraries, homegroup

I have 2 Windows 7 PCs in a home network. When I create a homegroup, the libraries I share are visible on the opposing machine but when I doubleclick them nothing happens - no error message, nothing at all. It is the same on both computers.

The homegroup works to the extent that the printer I shared is visible and can print from the other computer. Only the libraries are inaccessible.

What I tried and checked so far, without result:

- disabling firewall
- file and printer sharing, MS Networks client enabled in network properties
- deleting and recreating homegroup
- reset homegroup by deleting C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Roaming\PeerNetworking
- unsharing and sharing again the libraries

Comment: If you try via the command line, what happens?

Comment: I have no idea how to cd to a library or a homegroup share via commandline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading about the Homegroup internals it seems to me that there is a problem with the HomeGroupUser$ account. Either it does not exist or does not work.

As a workaround I added the built in Guest account on each of the computers to the HomeGroupUsers$ security group and the Homegroup started working again.